# How to implement barcode scanning in a Flutter desktop app using a barcode scanner?

Tags: flutter, desktop-application, barcode-scanner

I am building a pos system for desktop in flutter.I want to implement barcode scanning using barcode scanner, i am stuck on it. I appreciate any advice or pointers you can provide to help me get started on the right track. Thank you!

What packages or libraries are available for barcode scanning in Flutter desktop apps?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no solid solution for all desktop platforms. So for macOS I would recommend [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner) plugin. It has solid ranking and worked good for me. In case if you need windows then [simple_barcode_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_barcode_scanner) can be a good option.

In case if you need both only option I see is to have both plugins in place